# Using urxvtc to run a command

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, rxvt

I usually used to have this as one of my startup programs in a Linux system:

```
urxvt -e screen
```

But recently I have switched to using the daemon and client of `urxvt` i.e `urxvtd` and `urxvtc`. So I have been using `urxvtc` to request a new terminal window. Is there a similar way for invoking `screen` (or any other command for that matter) when used along with `urxvtc` ?

These is the configuration of my system:

```
Window manager: Xmonad
Linux kernel: 4.15.0
```

Note that just invoking `urxvtc` from a terminal works. But if I do `urxtc -e screen`, it seems to open a new terminal window and close it instantaneously.  Infact just issuing this command works: `urxtc -e sh`, but when using `screen` - it just fails.

Comment: `urxvtc -e screen`...

Comment: @jasonwryan Facepalm! I did try that inside a shell and it didn't seem to work. But trying `urxvt -e screen` also doesn't seem to work under the shell. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry for the late reply, but that's not working.

Comment: Works fine for me. Edit more detail into your question: what startup program, what environment, WM/DE? etc...